Continuous function between an interval
Given a positive integer $n\geq3$ , for each non-empty subset of ${1,r,r^2,...,r^{n-1}}$, calculate the arithmetic mean. Are there infinite $r$ and $n$ such that two unique subsets have the same arithmetic mean?

Since $S\subset[ 1,r^{n-1}]$ or $S\subset[r^{n-1},1]$, and $|S|=2^n-1$, the minimum gap is not larger than $\frac{|r^{n-1}-1|}{2^n}$

Let $S_n=\{ 1,r,r^2,\ldots ,r^n\}$.  There are infinitely many $n$ and $r$ such that the min gap equals $0$ for distinct subsets of $S_n$.
 Proposition: For any $k\geq 2$ and $n>k$, there exists a real number $r\in (k,k+1)$ such that the min gap is $0$ for distinct sets $S\subset S_n$ and $R\subset S_n$. 
Proof: For $x\in [k,k+1]$, let $S(x)=\{ x^{n-1} \}$ and $R(x)=\{ 1,x,\ldots , x^{k-1}, x^n\}$.  The arithmetic mean for $S(x)$ is $x^{n-1}$.  For $R(x)$, first notice: $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x^i = \frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$.  Thus, the arithmetic mean for $R(x)$ equals $$\frac{1}{k+1}\Big( x^n + \frac{x^k-1}{x-1}\Big) .$$ Define $f(x)=(k+1) x^{n-1} - x^n - \frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$.  Note $f(k)=k^{n-1}-\frac{k^k-1}{k-1}>0$, since $n-1 \geq k$.  Also, $f(k+1)=-\frac{(k+1)^k-1}{k} < 0$.  Since $f$ is continuous on the interval $[k,k+1]$, by Bolzano's intermediate value theorem, there exists $r\in (k,k+1)$ such that $f(r)=0$.
Therefore, the difference in the arithmetic means of $S(r)$ and $R(r)$ equals $\frac{1}{k+1} f(r) = 0$. QED
